# Pandas groupby cumulative/rolling sum,average, and std

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby, cumulative-sum

I have a dataframe (`df`) that is like the one below:

```
month-year    name    a    b    c
2018-01       X       2    1    4
2018-01       Y       1    0    5
2018-01       X       1    6    3
2018-01       Y       4    10   7
2018-02       X       13   4    2
2018-02       Y       22   13   9
2018-02       X       3    7    4
2018-02       Y       2    15   0
```

I want to `groupby` `month-year` and `name` to get the sum of column `a`, average of column `b`, and std of column `c`. However, I want the sum, average, and std to be a rolling/cumulative number.

For example, for this dataset, to find the output I want for a, I can do something like

`df.groupby(['month_year','name']).agg(sum).groupby(level=[1]).agg({'a':np.cumsum})`

to get something like

```
month-year    name    a
2018-01       X       3
              Y       5
2018-02       X       19
              Y       29
```

What can I do to find the cumulative average of `b` and std of `c` to get an output that looks like this?

```
month-year    name    a    b    c
2018-01       X       3    3.5  0.71
              Y       5    5    1.41
2018-02       X       19   4.5  0.96
              Y       29   9.5  3.86
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `expanding`

The first step is to calculate the expanding sum, mean and std for each of your columns, grouping only by `'name'` and to join that back to the original `DataFrame`.

Then you want to groupby and select the last row within each `['month-year', 'name']` group.

```
df = df.join(df.groupby(['name']).expanding().agg({'a': sum, 'b': 'mean', 'c': 'std'})
               .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
               .add_suffix('_roll'))

df.groupby(['month-year', 'name']).last().drop(columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Output:

```
                 a_roll  b_roll    c_roll
month-year name                          
2018-01    X        3.0     3.5  0.707107
           Y        5.0     5.0  1.414214
2018-02    X       19.0     4.5  0.957427
           Y       29.0     9.5  3.862210
```