# Rolling average over a window that is changing ( depends on other column)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following df

| used_id | Date | Rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Aug 1 | 5 |
| 1 | Aug 1 | 5 |
| 1 | Aug 2 | 1 |
| 1 | Aug 5 | 1 |
| 2 | July 5 | 4 |
| 2 | July 6 | 5 |

How can I create the Rolling_average column?

| used_id | Date | Rating | Rolling_avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Aug 1 | 5 | 5 |
| 1 | Aug 1 | 5 | 5 |
| 1 | Aug 2 | 1 | 3.66 |
| 1 | Aug 5 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | July 5 | 4 | 4 |
| 2 | July 6 | 5 | 4.5 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas groupby cumulative/rolling sum,average, and std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51751128/pandas-groupby-cumulative-rolling-sum-average-and-std)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can groupby `used_id` then call expanding and mean subsequently for `Rating` column, assign it back to the new column `Rolling_avg`:

```py
>>>(df.assign(Rolling_avg=df.groupby('used_id')['Rating']
                            .transform(lambda x:x.expanding().mean()))
 )

   used_id    Date  Rating  Rolling_avg
0        1   Aug 1       5     5.000000
1        1   Aug 1       5     5.000000
2        1   Aug 2       1     3.666667
3        1   Aug 5       1     3.000000
4        2  July 5       4     4.000000
5        2  July 6       5     4.500000
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, this worked. Now I just need to study how it worked :)

Comment: @Marat, you can first try to understand the part of getting the cumulative mean, by: `df.groupby('used_id')['Rating'].expanding().mean()`